# How do I rename the rows in the observation

Tags: sas, sas-studio

here I am using proc freq

```
Proc freq data=external_raw;
    table Marital_status;
run;
```

this the table the shows up:

| Marital_status | Frequency | Percent | Cumulative Frequency | Cumulative Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15851 | 8.38 | 15851 | 8.38 |
| 2 | 122370 | 64.68 | 138221 | 73.06 |
| 3 | 2645 | 1.40 | 140866 | 74.45 |
| 4 | 10216 | 5.40 | 151082 | 79.85 |
| 5 | 32141 | 16.99 | 183223 | 96.84 |
| 9 | 5975 | 3.16 | 189198 | 100.00 |

I want to change 1="Single", 2= "Married", 3= "Separated", 4= "Divorced", 5= "Widowed" and 9= "Unknown".

**Screenshot of above table**
[image: screenshot of above table]

Comment: Look into using PROC FORMAT to create a format which you can then use on Marital status values in a format statement. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/statug/statug_freq_details02.htm

Comment: You can try if or format.

Answer (score 1):

Format it with `proc format`.

```
proc format;
    value status
        1 = 'Single'
        2 = 'Married'
        3 = 'Separated'
        4 = 'Divored'
        5 = 'Widowed'
        9 = 'Unknown'
    ;
run;
```

Then apply the format:

```
proc freq data=have;
    format marital_status status.;

    table marital_status;
run;
```